# In Symfony: bin/behat --init and bin/behat @MyBundle --init do the same thing

Tags: symfony, behat

I have been told that for Symfony project I have to initialize bahat like this:

```
bin/behat @MyBundle --init
```

It suppose to create all new files inside the bundle. But I can see the features/ and features/bootstrap/ in the root of my project instead.

My question is: what is the difference between

```
bin/behat @MyBundle --init
```

and

```
bin/behat --init
```

Thanks.

P.S. here is my behat.yml file (it is in the root of my project)

```
# behat.yml
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
            base_url: http://myproject.dev/app_dev.php
```

and here is the packages that I've installed:

```
"behat/behat": "dev-master",
"behat/mink-extension": "dev-master",
"behat/mink": "dev-master",
"behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master",
"behat/symfony2-extension": "dev-master",
"behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "dev-master",
"behat/mink-goutte-driver": "dev-master"
```

Comment: Is the Symfony2 extension enabled in your `behat.yml`?

Comment: Yes it is? Look at my AppKernel.php file that I've provided please.

Comment: you didn't provide an `AppKernel.php`

Comment: Hi Kix, you are right sorry for that. Is it should look like this:
            new Behat\Symfony2Extension\ServiceContainer\Symfony2Extension(),

Comment: see this tutorial it helped me to configure behat and get it to work http://www.caillarec-coste.fr/behat-3-and-the-symfony-2-extension/